# When are double quotes required to create a KDB/q symbol?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Normally, for simple character strings, a leading backtick does the trick.

Example: `` `abc ``

However, if the string has some special characters, such as space, this will not work.

- Example: `` `$"abc def" ``
- Example: `` `$"BAT-3Kn.BK" ``

What are the rules when `$""` is required?

Answer (score 4):

Simple syntax for symbols can be used when the symbol consists of alphanumeric characters, dots (.), colons (:), and (non-leading) underscores (_).  In addition, slashes (/) are allowed when there is a colon before it.  Everything else requires the `$"" syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The book 'Q for mortals', which is available [online](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/), has a section discussing datatypes. For [symbols](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/2_Basic_Data_Types_Atoms/#242-symbol) it states:

> A symbol can include arbitrary text, including text that cannot be
>   directly entered from the console – e.g., embedded blanks and special
>   characters such as back-tick. You can manufacture a symbol from any
>   text by casting the corresponding list of char to a symbol. (You will
>   need to escape special characters into the string.) See §6.1.5 for
>   more on casting.
>
> ```
> q)`$"A symbol with blanks and `"
> `A symbol with blanks and `
> ```

The essential takeaway here is that converting a string to a symbol is required when special characters are involved. In the examples you have given both space `" "` and hyphen `"-"` are characters that cannot be directly placed into a symbol type.